# Fee Paid vs Confirmation Time

Tags: transaction-fees, confirmations

I there a graph correlating fee size and confirmation time?

A graph where I can see the fee paid by transactions which got confirmed in less than 20 minutes. Is there a graph like that?

Comment: All you should care about is time to first confirmation. The rest is random and independent of the fee paid.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz OK, I changed that part of the question.

Comment: It should likely be fee/byte vs confirmation time, not just fee.

Answer (score 3):

I put together this script that spits out a table of exactly that information directly from your full node:

`fees`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

getprice () {
  curl -sL 'https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/tickers?symbols=tBTCUSD' | jq '.[0][1]'
  #curl -sL 'https://api.quadrigacx.com/v2/ticker' | jq -r .last
}

n=${1:-100}
size=${2:-226}
price=${3:-$(getprice)}

for x in $(seq 1 $n)
do
  bitcoin-cli estimatesmartfee $x
done \
  | sed -e 's,\(0.[0-9]\+\),"\1",g' \
  | jq -r "[.feerate, .blocks, (((.blocks * 10)/60)*100 | floor)/100, (.feerate | tonumber | ((. * $size)/1000) * $price) ] | @tsv" \
  | sort -n -u -t$'\t' -k1,1 \
  | tac \
  | column -t -s $'\t'
```

usage:

All arguments are options. jq required.

```
fees [blocks] [tx size] [price]
```

outputs:

```
feerate     blocks  hours   fees (fiat)
0.00128259  2       0.33    1.65150777465
0.00110992  3       0.5     1.4291718392
0.00105930  6       1       1.3639917555
0.00100597  8       1.33    1.29532218095
0.00096015  13      2.16    1.23632274525
0.00091192  14      2.33    1.1742201092
0.00082616  15      2.5     1.0637925316
0.00079090  17      2.83    1.0183905215
0.00056060  20      3.33    0.7218481809999999
0.00005352  25      4.16    0.06891422520000001
0.00005093  61      10.16   0.06557925055000001
```

then you can

```
bitcoin-cli settxfee 0.00105930
```

the satoshis per byte are simply

```
$ bc <<< '(0.00105930 * 100000000)/1000'

105
```

Comment: I now have a github repo for this: https://github.com/jb55/bitcoin-fees

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of this question's PageRank, there is now such a service:
  https://bitcoinfees.21.co/
.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a similar graph here

https://estimatesmartfee.com/

It shows how much fee transactions pay and how long they are in mempool. (Which is different from what you are asking, but similar.)

It's not very pretty, since I didn't have time to add CSS yet.

Note that it doesn't get CPFP into account at all.